# How can I use the parallel command while getting parameters dynamically from a file?

Tags: command-line, parallelism

Let's say I have a `file` listing the path of multiple files like the following:

```
/home/user/file1.txt
/home/user/file2.txt
/home/user/file3.txt
/home/user/file4.txt
/home/user/file5.txt
/home/user/file6.txt
/home/user/file7.txt
```

Let's also say that I want to copy those files in parallel 3 by 3. I know that with the command `parallel` I can execute a specific command in parallel as the following:

```
parallel bash -c "echo hello world" -- 1 2 3
```

However, this way of running `parallel` is hardcoded because even if I use a variable inside the quotes, it will only have a fixed parameter. I'd like to execute the `parallel` command getting parameters dynamically from a file. As an example, let's say I'd like to copy all files from my `file` running three parallel processes (something like `cp "$file" /home/user/samplefolder/`). How can I do it? Is there any parameter I can use with `parallel` to accomplish that and get parameters dynamically from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GNU Parallel you can do one of these:

```
parallel cp {} destination/folder/ :::: filelist
parallel -a filelist cp {} destination/folder/
cat filelist | parallel cp {} destination/folder/
```

Consider spending 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of the GNU Parallel 2018 book (print: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html online: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014). Your command line will love you for it.